# Kendo grid data not displaying when pageSize is set dynamically by window screen size

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to set pagesize of the grid dynamically with the window size and populate the data items/rows inside it. I've added a function to calculate how many rows the grid can fit in. I've tested the function and it works correctly. But the thing is the data items/rows are not displayed inside the grid. FYI: here, I am just using local datasource as a testing purpose.

Calculating rows function:

```
  function RowCount(){
  var TableHead = $('.k-grid-header').height();  
  var WWidth = $(window).height(); 
  var  TablePager = Math.round($('.k-grid-pager').height());
  var ExtraSpace=TableHead+TablePager;
  var EachRow=$('td:first-child').height();
  var  GridContent = Math.round(WWidth-ExtraSpace);
  var Rows=Math.round((WWidth-ExtraSpace)/EachRow);
    //return (Rows);
     alert(Rows);
  }
```

Finally re binding with grid and getting the data:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
//grid.hideColumn(0); 
    grid.bind("dataBound", RowCount);
    grid.dataSource.fetch();
```

However, data items/rows are not displayed.
Where am I doing wrong? I've also set `autobindig: false`
And this is my dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/afUZeL/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a RowCount until the grid is loaded. You can't load the grid without know the PageSize.

I would suggest you set an initial size and then refresh with your calculations using the pagesize of the datasource.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
//grid.hideColumn(0); 
//grid.bind("dataBound",RowCount);
//grid.dataSource.fetch();
grid.dataSource.pageSize(RowCount());
grid.refresh();
```

Comment: Yes, now I can populate the data items inside the grid.

Comment: However my pagination is not giving that computed number of rows. It is displaying all the rows with scroll bar, when it is in full screen mode. It is supposed to be "14"rows in the grid, then go to next page,...etc.